# Understanding closure syntax

Tags: swift

I'm studying closures and wonder why following not work:

```
let names = ["Scarlet", "Stan", "Mike", "Walter", "Jessie"]
var sortedClosure : (_ : String, _ : String) -> Bool

sortedClosure = { $0 > $1 }

names.sort(by: sortedClosure)
```

Error says:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

But function sorted by declared as following:

```
sorted(by: { (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in }
```

Comment: What's `names`? (please provide a [mcve]) Is it declared as a `let` by any chance? `sort` mutates the collection in-place, so it needs to be a `var`.

Comment: So it *is* declared as a `let` – change it to a `var`

Comment: @Hamish that code work with let variable names, why? names.sorted(by: { (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in
    return s1 > s2
})

Comment: `sorted(by:)` doesn't mutate the collection, it returns a new array. `let sorted = names.sorted(by: sortedClosure)` should also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mutate the array `names` you must make it a variable. The code below works:

```
var names = ["Scarlet", "Stan", "Mike", "Walter", "Jessie"]
var sortedClosure : (_ : String, _ : String) -> Bool   // declares closure
sortedClosure = { $0 > $1 }   // initializes closure
```

And after this you have two options:

- applying `sorted(by:)` and assigning it to the array:

  ```
  names = names.sorted(by: sortedClosure)  // applies sorted(by:) and assigns the array to the newly created one
  ```
- applying `sort(by:)`, which mutates the array:

  ```
  names.sort(by: sortedClosure)
  ```

When you first called `sort(by:)`, you received the error because your `names` was a let constant. Since `sort(by:)` mutates the Array, it must be a variable.

---

However, for what you want to do, I personally wouldn't do it this way. For just sorting the array in "descending" alphabetical order, you should try this:

```
names.sort(by: >)
```

Comment: Xcode thanks, what exactly mean names.sort(by: >)? What closure is called when we pass ">" after by:?

Comment: It is passed as something equivalent to your sortedClosure